# Whats wrong with this code

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am following [this example](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/20/Example-of-PhoneGaps-Database-Support)

I have looked at the code over and over again and it seems nearly identical to the example however getOrdersSuccess never gets called. The log shows "setupTable" and "getOrders" both get called. Nothing from getOrdersSuccess ever gets logged.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if( window.isphone ) {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "The Database", 200000);
    db.transaction(setupTable, errorCB, getOrders);
    }
}
function setupTable(tx){
    $('#log').append("<p>setupTable</p>");
        tx.executeSql('create table if not exists orders (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name, isSubmitted, date)');
}
function getOrders() {
        $('#log').append("<p>getOrders</p>");
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT Id, name FROM orders', [], getOrdersSuccess, errorCB);
        }, errorCB);
    }
    // Query the success callback
    //
function getOrdersSuccess(tx, results) {
    $('#log').append("<p>getOrdersSuccess</p>");
        var len = results.rows.length;
        $('#log').append("<p>Orders table: " + len + " rows found.</p>");
        $('#current').html('');
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            $('#log').append("<p>Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).Id + " Name =  " + results.rows.item(i).name + "</p>");
            $('#current').append('<p>'+results.rows.item(i).Id+'---'+results.rows.item(i).name+'</p>');
        }
    }
function errorCB(err) {
        $('#log').append("<p>Error processing SQL: "+err.code+"</p>");
    }
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I updated the question to include the error function. The log does not throw the error. I don't see any error when I run the application on my nexus. The code posted is part of a phone gap application. I haven't really figured out phonegap debugging yet. I guess I should probably look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `var db;` outside of any function and then revise `onDeviceReady` like this:

```
var db;
function onDeviceReady() {
    if( window.isphone ) {
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "The Database", 200000);
        db.transaction(setupTable, errorCB, getOrders);
    }
}
```

The issue is, if you define `var db` inside of `onDeviceReady` it is scoped to that function and not accessible in the function `getOrders`

Comment: Thank you very much! As soon as I read this I wanted to punch myself in the face and hug you all at the same time.